# jboss 4.2.2 to 5.0.1 migration:needed jboss client jar files

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x

im switching jboss 4.2.2 to 5.0.1 and i have installed jboss. now on client side i replaced existing jar files. jbossall-client.jar,jboss-client.jar,commons-logging.jar,jboss-serialization.jar,jnp-client.jar. but still error came on logging.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/jboss/logging/Logger at
>   org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.(NamingContext.java:160)

could anyone shed some light.

note:(when i copy all 90 jars from jboss-5.0.1.GA\client into my client lib, my APPLICATION WORKING. but i don know what are the remaining jars exactly needed.) :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `org.jboss.logging` API classes are in `jboss-logging-spi.jar`. You'll probably also need either `jboss-logging-jdk.jar` or `jboss-logging-log4j.jar`.

In JBoss 4, the `jbossall-client.jar` contained a copy of every class that client applications might need. As of v5, though, it contains only a manifest file that refers to the other JARs, and so simply including `jbossall-client.jar` is no longer enough, you need to include the others as well.

Comment: thanks. i have copied those. now the error differs.
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.naming.Reference cannot be cast

Comment: That means you have multiple copies of `javax.naming.Reference`. But please don't just stick additional questions as comments to the answer - accept each answer and move on to the next question.